# How to partition a box

Tags: modeling

I would like to partition a box into 3 divisions
Then make it 3d printable
I have tried the Solidify Modifier and the Loop cut
The box would be used a tray for small parts

---

[image]

Thanks for your reply
This is what I have in mind

Comment: Hi. If I understand well, you want a tray with 3 compartments ? Could you show of a drawing of what you want ?

Comment: OK, I did not saw your edit in between. Is the current answer enough ?

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach can be the use of knife project (but depending on the shapes you want for the compartments) :

Here I started from a cube and planes giving the shape of the compartments.

- Select the planes <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Add the cube to the selection <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> so that both are selected and the cube is the active object.
- Go top view <kbd>Numpad7</kbd>
- Wireframe mode to have a better visibility <kbd>Z</kbd>
- Enter edit mode (that will edit the cube but keeping the planes selected) <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Use '*knife project*' (don't check *cut through* as we want to keep the base intact)
- Then extrude down the compartments <kbd>E</kbd> along Z axis

[image]

Edit : following the comment, I add here the blend file with step by step explanations :

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would like more detail about individual step.
Thanks so for you effort

Comment: @Harry, the answer is updated. I think you have here all the details you need. Tell me...